# Why the torus has open subsets diffeomorphic to a cylinder?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

If I take the torus $T$ of revolution in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is very intuitive for me that there is an open subset of $T$ that is diffeomorphic to a cylinder, for example $T$ minus a circle on the $xz$ plane. But how can I prove this in a rigourous way? This problem appeared to me when I learn how to calculate the cohomology groups of the deRham complex of $T$, where is assumed that we can take such a type of open subsets, and we use those open sets in the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence. Can anyone give me a help? Thanks.

Comment: It's analogous to a diffeomorphism between an arc of circle and a straight segment.

Comment: @Berci Yeah, but how can I construct such a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of the torus. For instance, if the torus is $S^1 \times S^1$ then you might remove $\{x_0\} \times S^1$.

We know $(S^1 \times S^1) \setminus (\{x_0\} \times S^1)$ is the same thing as $(S^1 \setminus \{x_0\}) \times S^1$, but it's pretty easy to see that $S^1 \setminus \{x_0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $(0,1)$, which means our set is diffeomorphic to $(0,1) \times S^1$, a cylinder.

---

I hope this helps ^_^